# 2 tables - Select a row from different table when column value changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2016

This is in MS SSMS 2016. I have two tables - SHIPMENT_HEADER and SHIPMENT_DETAIL.

```
SHIPMENT_HEADER

shipment_id |  customer  | 
------------|------------|
SH001       |    cust1   |
SH002       |    cust2   |
```

Shipment_detail has similar columns

```
SHIPMENT_DETAIL

shipment_id | customer | item   | requested_qty|
------------|----------|--------|--------------|
SH001       |   cust1  |  item1 |    2         |
SH001       |   cust1  |  item2 |    2         |
SH001       |   cust1  |  item3 |    1         |
SH002       |   cust2  |  item1 |    2         |
SH002       |   cust2  |  item2 |    2         |
```

I'm wondering if it's possible at all to write something so that for every shipment_id, it returns the shipment_header details, with the shipment_details listed underneath, so:

```
shipment_id | instruction  |customer | item   | requested_qty|
------------|--------------|---------|--------|--------------|
SH001       |    HEADER    |  cust1  |  NULL  |    5         |
SH001       |    DETAIL    |  cust1  |  item1 |    2         |
SH001       |    DETAIL    |  cust1  |  item2 |    2         |
SH001       |    DETAIL    |  cust1  |  item3 |    1         |
SH002       |    HEADER    |  cust2  |  NULL  |    4         |
SH002       |    DETAIL    |  cust2  |  item1 |    2         |
SH002       |    DETAIL    |  cust2  |  item2 |    2         |
```

I thought maybe a UNION to select the header and then the details, but if I query multiple shipments at once, it selects all the headers then all the details, instead of header-details, header-details.

What I have so far is basically just selecting the each bit separately. This was written with UNION in mind, so some of the NULL columns are probably unneeded if another method is used

```
SELECT
SH.SHIPMENT_ID 'SHIPMENT_ID', 
'HEADER' AS 'INSTRUCTION_TYPE',
SH.CUSTOMER 'CUSTOMER', 
NULL 'ITEM',
B.TOTAL_QTY
FROM SHIPMENT_HEADER SH
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SHIPMENT_ID, SUM(REQUESTED_QTY) 'TOTAL_QTY'
    FROM SHIPMENT_DETAIL
    GROUP BY SHIPMENT_ID
    ) AS B
ON SH.SHIPMENT_ID = B.SHIPMENT_ID
WHERE SH.SHIPMENT_ID IN ('SH001','SH002')
UNION
SELECT 
SD.SHIPMENT_ID,
'SHIPMENT_DETAIL' AS 'INSTRUCTION_TYPE',
SD.CUSTOMER,
SD.ITEM,
SD.REQUESTED_QTY
FROM SHIPMENT_DETAIL SD
WHERE SD.SHIPMENT_ID IN (
'SH001', 'SH002'
)
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following statement :

```
(
SELECT header.shipment_id, 'HEADER' as 'instruction', header.customer, NULL as 'item', SUM(requested_qty) as 'requested_qty'
FROM SHIPMENT_HEADER header
LEFT JOIN SHIPMENT_DETAIL detail
ON header.shipment_id = detail.shipment_id
AND header.customer = detail.customer
GROUP BY header.shipment_id, header.customer
)
UNION
(
SELECT shipment_id, 'DETAIL', customer, item, requested_qty
FROM SHIPMENT_DETAIL
)
ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC, 3, 4
```

It gives the following results

```
shipment_id instruction customer   item       requested_qty
----------- ----------- ---------- ---------- -------------
SH001       HEADER      cust1      NULL       5
SH001       DETAIL      cust1      item1      2
SH001       DETAIL      cust1      item2      2
SH001       DETAIL      cust1      item3      1
SH002       HEADER      cust2      NULL       4
SH002       DETAIL      cust2      item1      2
SH002       DETAIL      cust2      item2      2
```

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you, I managed to get exactly what I needed just by using different a different order by. Embarrassingly simple...many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Here I am assuming that for a `shipment_id` you have same `customer`, as per your example. If that is not the case, you have to tell, which `customer` you want to show with `HEADER` record.

Edit: Used a CTE to consider only the records which are in `SHIPMENT_HEADER` and `SHIPMENT_DETAIL` both.

```
with t_SHIPMENT_DETAIL as
(SELECT d.shipment_id,
               d.customer,
               d.item,
               d.requested_qty
       FROM SHIPMENT_DETAIL d
       inner join
       SHIPMENT_HEADER h
        on d.shipment_id=h.shipment_id
)
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT shipment_id,
           'HEADER' AS instruction,
           customer,
           NULL AS item,
           sum(requested_qty) AS requested_qty
   FROM t_SHIPMENT_DETAIL
   GROUP BY shipment_id,
            customer

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT shipment_id,
            'DETAIL' AS instruction,
            customer,
            item,
            requested_qty
   FROM t_SHIPMENT_DETAIL 
   )
ORDER BY shipment_id,
         instruction DESC
```

Explanation: First query in union is getting the `sum(requested_qty)` group by `shipment_id, customer`. And we are hardcoding `HEADER` and `null` for item here. Now second part of union is your current query shipment detail, except for an extra column `DETAIL`. It is to match columns in `UNION`

At last, just encapsulate this in an select clause for `order by`.

Comment: This query allows you to extract a header that is not inserted into SHIPMENT_HEADER table. Seems a bit wrong.